# Not Able to Set Title of Tab in Console after Case Creation

Tags: console

I have the Below Page as in SFDC Help - Tried to achieve the name 
First - it's loading As 'Case Creation' after Save also it shows as 'Case Creation' only for Tab name ,I need to show the Newly Created Record Name here in the tab Title. please suggest something here to achieve it

**My Page :**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="consoleTab" sidebar="true" showHeader="true">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/26.0/integration.js" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            < body onload = "testSetTabTitle()" / >
        </script>
        <apex:commandLink value=" Create New Case" action="{!goToCaseEditPage}" />
        <br></br>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/35.0/integration.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var g_subId;
        function testGetFocusedSubtabId() {
            sforce.console.getFocusedSubtabId(showTabId);
        }
        var showTabId = function showTabId(result) {
            g_subId = result.id;
        };
        function testSetTabTitle() {
            //Set the current tab's title
            sforce.console.setTabTitle('Case Creation');
        }
        function testOpenSubtab() {
            sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
        }
        var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result) {
            var primaryTabId = result.id;
            sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId, '/500/e?cas7=Escalated&cas11=Phone', true, '', g_subId, openSuccess, null);
        };
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page isn't a valid HTML page. You have a body tag inside of a script tag, and it's trying to call an out-of-scope function. I'd also recommend removing the duplicate calls to integration.js and using a more robust method to use onload. I'd also suggest using your browser's built in debugging tools to help pinpoint errors when writing JavaScript.

Sample working code is below:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="consoleTab" sidebar="true" showHeader="true">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandLink value=" Create New Case" action="{!goToCaseEditPage}" />
        <br></br>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/35.0/integration.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var oldonload = window.onload; 
      if (typeof window.onload != 'function') 
      { 
         window.onload = testSetTabTitle; 
      } 
      else
      { 
          window.onload = function()  
          { 
            if (oldonload) 
            { 
               oldonload(); 
            } 
            testSetTabTitle(); 
          } 
       } 

        var g_subId;
        function testGetFocusedSubtabId() {
            sforce.console.getFocusedSubtabId(showTabId);
        }
        var showTabId = function showTabId(result) {
            g_subId = result.id;
        };
        function testSetTabTitle() {
            //Set the current tab's title
            sforce.console.setTabTitle('Case Creation');
        }
        function testOpenSubtab() {
            sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
        }
        var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result) {
            var primaryTabId = result.id;
            sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId, '/500/e?cas7=Escalated&cas11=Phone', true, '', g_subId, openSuccess, null);
        };
    </script>
</apex:page>
```